# Referencing cell data, and corresponding row data, on another sheet

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, vlookup, xlookup

Working in Excel, I’m attempting to do the following. I have a template worksheet that holds all of my data, and a reporting worksheet where I report all of said data out. Same workbook. The template worksheet can have varying lengths of data in the range of cells (i.e. 90k rows for one column in one circumstance, and 75k rows another time)

Within this worksheet, I’m reporting out multiple bits of high-frequency data:
Time (sec)
Pressure (BAR)
RPM
Hi-Flow (flow meter kg/m)
Lo-Flow (flow meter kg/m)

What I’m attempting to do, is have a report that will reference the cells in Column A (Time) and upon finding the seconds (10,20,30…90) then reference the next column I would request (Either RPM or Pressure) and have it find the corresponding value in the SAME row as the time column. (IE, 10 seconds sits at A6570, so the cell would reference B6570 on my template, and then paste that value into the reporting template)

Said column could find it based on the whole column, as the length of rows will vary from test-to-test. Need something that can be variable.

I’m lost on if I should use the XLookup and have it reference the other sheet? The data is quite large to where I’d like to have them on separate sheets, and it would be easier for reporting it out on my end.

End goal for it is have the following:

Report has 10-90 seconds listed

Report then finds the 10-90 second value within the other worksheet

Report then references that same worksheet, finds the corresponding cell in the next reference column (RPM/Pressure/etc.) and reports it out in a destination cell

Not sure what else I can do, still learning excel and VBA.

Thank you for your time looking at this post!

I tried to use XLookup but I’m not sure how best to reference the other sheet and corresponding values. Kind of at a loss as how best to go about this.

(Edited to add screenshots for reference) In example 1, you can see the destination I would like them to be in. Columns in reference to 10, 20...90, due right of the scatter plot. For ease the 10,20 values are set in columns S,T merged together. Pressure and RPM both merged as well.
Then, in example 2, you can see where I'm pulling said data from. This is from a separate worksheet Called "Test_Data"

[image: Example1]

[image: Example2]

Comment: No screenshots or sample data, so it's difficult to suggest answers here...

Comment: Try Xlookup, yes you can reference a column in another sheet or multiple sheets. Once you master this formula, everything else gets easier. Many videos on youtube if you learn better that way.

Comment: If you're having difficulty with `xlookup`, try `Index(...,Match(...,...,...))`. They work, ~roughly~ the same, but you can start with just the Match to make sure you're finding the cell location properly, then add the index around it.

Comment: Also, here's an example of Xlookup working on a different sheet `=XLOOKUP("test value",Sheet1!C356:C377,Sheet2!C356:C377)`

Comment: Edited to add in the new screenshots. I'll attempt a little bit of the coding here later this week most likely. Any insight into it outside of that would be great! Thank you Cameron for the information. I'll give that a shot.
@TimWilliams screenshots now attached

Comment: This will be easy to do, actually, but I still have more questions than answers right now.  (a) What is the logic?  Meaning, there is no value at exactly 10.0 seconds, so what do you do?  Next higher? Next lower? Interpolate?  (b) Wondering why you merged cells together for "ease"...  Merging almost always complicates rather than simplifies things and I would recommend avoiding it.  (c) it looks like pressure is sampled at 1kHz but RPM and flow are arbitrary intervals that average 4-5 Hz?  So does the pressure in C25 correlate to the RPM in E25, or are these separate lookups?

Comment: @MaxR There will always be a value at 10 seconds based on our data acquisition. The way our test runs will always give a correlating value. I merged the cells at the top for the title and for making them larger. If it complicates things it’s easy enough to just bring them back to single cell format. And we scan various components at high/low frequency, but no matter what our time table will always be the same. On image 2, I have two separate sections with the time and variables. That’s our low/high scan rates. Time in A1000 for example will reference B1000 for RPM and C1000 for Pressure, etc..

Comment: TECHNICALLY our time table won’t be the same, at least with the data points, but they will always at least give a data point at the times I listed that we can reference to and will be accurate.

Comment: @MaxR Actually just noticed that the low speed does have varying sections on that due to its scan rate. High speed always has the 10 listed. Would indeed need to do some form of logic check. Possibly a <= on each end of the spectrum by like .2 seconds or so and snag a data point. It doesn’t need to be dead accurate, a rough interpolation would be acceptable for the low speed side of things.